# Fastest way to map result of SqlDataReader to object

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, dapper

I'm comparing materialize time between Dapper and ADO.NET and Dapper.  <s>Ultimately, Dapper tend to faster than ADO.NET, though the first time a given fetch query was executed is slower than ADO.NET.</s> a few result show that Dapper a little bit faster than ADO.NET(almost all of result show that it comparable though)
So I think I'm using inefficient approach to map result of SqlDataReader to object.
This is my code

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderID = @Id";
        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            for (var i = 0; i < keys.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (var r = 0; r < keys.GetLength(1); r++)
                {
                    stopWatch.Restart();
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", keys[i, r]);
                    var reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    SalesOrderHeaderSQLserver salesOrderHeader = null;

                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        salesOrderHeader = new SalesOrderHeaderSQLserver();
                        salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderId = (int)reader["SalesOrderId"];
                        salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber = reader["SalesOrderNumber"] as string;
                        salesOrderHeader.AccountNumber = reader["AccountNumber"] as string;
                        salesOrderHeader.BillToAddressID = (int)reader["BillToAddressID"];
                        salesOrderHeader.TotalDue = (decimal)reader["TotalDue"];
                        salesOrderHeader.Comment = reader["Comment"] as string;
                        salesOrderHeader.DueDate = (DateTime)reader["DueDate"];
                        salesOrderHeader.CurrencyRateID = reader["CurrencyRateID"] as int?;
                        salesOrderHeader.CustomerID = (int)reader["CustomerID"];
                        salesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = reader["SalesPersonID"] as int?;
                        salesOrderHeader.CreditCardApprovalCode = reader["CreditCardApprovalCode"] as string;
                        salesOrderHeader.ShipDate = reader["ShipDate"] as DateTime?;
                        salesOrderHeader.Freight = (decimal)reader["Freight"];
                        salesOrderHeader.ModifiedDate = (DateTime)reader["ModifiedDate"];
                        salesOrderHeader.OrderDate = (DateTime)reader["OrderDate"];
                        salesOrderHeader.TerritoryID = reader["TerritoryID"] as int?;
                        salesOrderHeader.CreditCardID = reader["CreditCardID"] as int?;
                        salesOrderHeader.OnlineOrderFlag = (bool)reader["OnlineOrderFlag"];
                        salesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber = reader["PurchaseOrderNumber"] as string;
                        salesOrderHeader.RevisionNumber = (byte)reader["RevisionNumber"];
                        salesOrderHeader.Rowguid = (Guid)reader["Rowguid"];
                        salesOrderHeader.ShipMethodID = (int)reader["ShipMethodID"];
                        salesOrderHeader.ShipToAddressID = (int)reader["ShipToAddressID"];
                        salesOrderHeader.Status = (byte)reader["Status"];
                        salesOrderHeader.SubTotal = (decimal)reader["SubTotal"];
                        salesOrderHeader.TaxAmt = (decimal)reader["TaxAmt"];
                    }

                    stopWatch.Stop();
                    reader.Close();
                    await PrintTestFindByPKReport(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderId.ToString());
                }
```

I used `as` keyword to cast in nullable column, is that correct?
and this is code for Dapper.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            for (var i = 0; i < keys.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (var r = 0; r < keys.GetLength(1); r++)
                {
                    stopWatch.Restart();
                    var result = (await conn.QueryAsync<SalesOrderHeader>("SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderID = @Id", new { Id = keys[i, r] })).FirstOrDefault();
                    stopWatch.Stop();
                    await PrintTestFindByPKReport(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, result.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if you remove the async code and compare that?

Comment: "Ultimately, Dapper tend to faster than ADO.NET" - sentence does not compute; Dapper sits **on  top of** ADO.NET; it cannot be *faster* than something it consumes, and ADO.NET *doesn't offer* the service you are after... can you be more specific about what you mean there?

Comment: It looks to  me like your main problem here  is that you're doing lots of  queries; have you considered using an INNER JOIN or multiple SELECT (`.QueryMultiple`) to do everything  in **one** query rather than doing multiple queries?

Comment: @MarcGravell When I asked this question I actually forgot that Dapper is on top of ADO.NET.  after I properly compared all of testing result(not just gazed at it).  I must admitted that I exaggerated, a few of result show that highest difference of time that Dapper is faster is 9 ms, the almost all of result show that it comparable, and few of it show that ADO.NET is faster.  I'm really sorry for wasted your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a way to make your ADO.NET code faster.

When you do your select, list out the fields that you are selecting rather than using select *.  This will let you ensure the order that the fields are coming back even if that order changes in the database.Then when getting those fields from the Reader, get them by index rather than by name.  Using and index is faster.

Also, I'd recommend not making string database fields nullable unless there is a strong business reason.  Then just store a blank string in the database if there is no value.  Finally I'd recommend using the `Get` methods on the `DataReader` to get your fields in the type they are so that casting isn't needed in your code.  So for example instead of casting the `DataReader[index++]` value as an int use `DataReader.GetInt(index++)`

So for example, this code:

```
 salesOrderHeader = new SalesOrderHeaderSQLserver();
 salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderId = (int)reader["SalesOrderId"];
 salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber =       reader["SalesOrderNumber"] as string;
 salesOrderHeader.AccountNumber = reader["AccountNumber"] as string;
```

becomes

```
 int index = 0;
 salesOrderHeader = new SalesOrderHeaderSQLserver();
 salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderId = reader.GetInt(index++);
 salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber = reader.GetString(index++);
 salesOrderHeader.AccountNumber = reader.GetString(index++);
```

Give that a whirl and see how it does for you.

Comment: Thank you, though I'm lazy to list all of column name and use `GetXXX` method that take position XD, it's prone to error when I map it to property.  However, if it faster, I'll try.  Can you explain string field shouldn't be nullable.

Comment: Maybe it's only worth doing where you need highly performant code.  Creating a code generator that can write chunks of this code for you is one way to solve the lazy issue, but alas that takes work too :-)

Comment: Just report result of testing, get value by position of column is faster than column name, in my case, it 1 ms faster though.  however, it proved that ADO.NET isn't  slower than Dapper and Dapper is comparable to ADO.NET in term of performance.

Comment: The caveat with ordinal based approach is now you have a tightly coupled order of columns in the query with the consuming of them. It's easy to get 1 list out of sync with the other and difficult to visually map the 2. I'm curious if there's a clean way to map the indices to column names before traversing such that you could get the performance of index lookup with the readability of column name lookup.

Comment: @bingles - You are tightly coupled to the order you specified the columns in your select statement, not the order of them in the db.  But, the performance difference between index access vs field name access isn't a lot anyway.  But of course index access is the fastest way to access the field.  If you access the field by name then you will need to incur the extra time it takes to locate that field. I wouldn't worry too much about the cost of accessing by name,  but then again for a small number of fields it's easy to access by index.

Comment: @bingles For readability, you could use constants. Continuing with the example from above:  
   const int SalesOrderId = 0;
   salesOrderHeader.SalesOrderId = reader.GetInt(SalesOrderId);
   ...

Answer (score 40):

When in doubt regarding anything db or reflection, I ask myself, "what would [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) do?".

In this case, he would use [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member)! And you should too. It's concepts are the underpinning to data conversions in [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), and can easily be used to map your own DataReader to an object (should you not want to use Dapper).

Below is an extension method converting a `SqlDataReader` into something of type `T`:

> PLEASE NOTE: This code implies a dependency on FastMember and is written for .NET Core (though could easily be converted to .NET Framework/Standard compliant code).

```
public static T ConvertToObject<T>(this SqlDataReader rd) where T : class, new()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type);
    var members = accessor.GetMembers();
    var t = new T();

    for (int i = 0; i < rd.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (!rd.IsDBNull(i))
        {
            string fieldName = rd.GetName(i);

            if (members.Any(m => string.Equals(m.Name, fieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                accessor[t, fieldName] = rd.GetValue(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: compared to Reflection, its much slower in my tests. if you cache the members you might get faster results the second time around.

Comment: @manit of course you should cache the accessor, otherwise you compile and emit the accessors every time.

Comment: Fastmember does that internally. But yes you could of course do that as well. This answer isn't meant to serve as a final solution. But rather a component in the overall design.

Answer (score 23):

### 2022 update

Now that we have .NET 5 and .NET 6 available, which include [Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) - an amazing Roslyn-based feature, that, basically, allows your code to... generate more code at compile time. It's basically "AOT Reflection" (ahead-of-time) that allows you to generate lightning-fast mapping code that has zero overhead. This thing will revolutionize the ORM world for sure.

Now, back to the question - *the fastest* way to map an `IDataReader` would be to use Source Generators. We started experimenting with this feature and we love it.

Here's a library we're working on, that does exactly that (maps `DataReader` to objects), feel free to "steal" some code examples: https://github.com/jitbit/MapDataReader

### Previous answer that is still 100% valid

The most upvoted answer mentions @MarkGravel and his FastMember. **But** if you're already using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), which is also a component of his, you can use Dapper's `GetRowParser` like this:

```
var parser = reader.GetRowParser<MyObject>(typeof(MyObject));

while (reader.Read())
{
    var myObject = parser(reader);
}
```

Comment: Even easier and working with >1 rows: conn.Query<salesOrderHeader>(sql)

Comment: `reader.GetRowParser(Type)` is perfect for reading into multiple objects when you dont know the type (generics/reflection)

Comment: Is it possible to have something parsed only once per Class and have an internal implementation cached?

Comment: @MaulikModi this is how Dapper works internally, it caches precompiled expressions

Comment: I would really like to use this solution however when I try this with an `INSERT INTO RETURNING *;` query in postgres the parser seems to ignore every field except for the first field.

Answer (score 9):

Modified @HouseCat's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918088) to be case insensitive:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a SqlDataReader record to an object. Ignoring case.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dataReader"></param>
    /// <param name="newObject"></param>
    /// <remarks>https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918088</remarks>
    public static void MapDataToObject<T>(this SqlDataReader dataReader, T newObject)
    {
        if (newObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newObject));

        // Fast Member Usage
        var objectMemberAccessor = TypeAccessor.Create(newObject.GetType());
        var propertiesHashSet =
                objectMemberAccessor
                .GetMembers()
                .Select(mp => mp.Name)
                .ToHashSet(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var name = propertiesHashSet.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Equals(dataReader.GetName(i), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                objectMemberAccessor[newObject, name]
                    = dataReader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : dataReader.GetValue(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This does not work for `List<T>` or multiple tables in the results.

EDIT2: Changing the calling function to this works for lists. I am just going to return a list of objects no matter what and get the first index if I was expecting a single object. I haven't looked into multiple tables yet but I will.

```
    public static void MapDataToObject<T>(this SqlDataReader dataReader, T newObject)
    {
        if (newObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newObject));

        // Fast Member Usage
        var objectMemberAccessor = TypeAccessor.Create(newObject.GetType());
        var propertiesHashSet =
                objectMemberAccessor
                .GetMembers()
                .Select(mp => mp.Name)
                .ToHashSet(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var name = propertiesHashSet.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Equals(dataReader.GetName(i), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                //Attention! if you are getting errors here, then double check that your model and sql have matching types for the field name.
                //Check api.log for error message!
                objectMemberAccessor[newObject, name]
                    = dataReader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : dataReader.GetValue(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 3: Updated to show sample calling function.

```
    public async Task<List<T>> ExecuteReaderAsync<T>(string storedProcedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        var newListObject = new List<T>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = GetSqlCommand(conn, storedProcedureName, sqlParameters))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                using (var dataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.Default))
                {
                    if (dataReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            var newObject = new T();
                            dataReader.MapDataToObject(newObject);
                            newListObject.Add(newObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return newListObject;
    }
```

Comment: @HouseCat Thanks, I have been using this function on multiple APIs for nearly 2 yrs now. The only issue I have is the occasional type mismatch between DB and model when adding new objects which I mitigated with a fancy comment.

Answer (score 8):

Took the method from [pimbrouwers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853182/3072640) and optimized it slightly. Reduce LINQ calls.

Maps only properties found in both the object and data field names. Handles DBNull. Other assumption made is your domain model properties absolutely equals table column/field names.

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps a SqlDataReader record to an object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="dataReader"></param>
/// <param name="newObject"></param>
public static void MapDataToObject<T>(this SqlDataReader dataReader, T newObject)
{
    if (newObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newObject));

    // Fast Member Usage
    var objectMemberAccessor = TypeAccessor.Create(newObject.GetType());
    var propertiesHashSet =
            objectMemberAccessor
            .GetMembers()
            .Select(mp => mp.Name)
            .ToHashSet();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (propertiesHashSet.Contains(dataReader.GetName(i)))
        {
            objectMemberAccessor[newObject, dataReader.GetName(i)]
                = dataReader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : dataReader.GetValue(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string storedProcedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = null) where T : class, new()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
        var sqlCommand = await GetSqlCommandAsync(storedProcedureName, conn, sqlParameters);
        var dataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            var newObject = new T();

            if (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
            { dataReader.MapDataToObject(newObject); }

            return newObject;
        }
        else
        { return null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This version is case sensitive, Oracle always returns column names uppercase

Comment: That is correct. The properties/columns must match and is case sensitive. You could however modify the objectMemberAccessor key to a string function of ToUpper() / ToLower(). If I ever do a version of Attributes I will modify this solution.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the approach I will present isn't the most efficient but gets the job done with very little coding effort. The main benefit I see here is that you don't have to deal with data structure other than building a compatible (mapable) object.

If you convert the `SqlDataReader` to `DataTable` then serialize it using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` you can then deserialize it to a known object type using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Here is an example of implementation:

```
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
        myConnection.Open();
        reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(reader);

        List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var serializedMyObjects = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
            // Here you get the object
            myObjects = (List<MyObject>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedMyObjects, typeof(List<MyObject>));
        }

        myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Tricky!  I like it.

Comment: DataTable is slow compared to a DataReader. If you are using the DataTable as your data model in your application then it is the faster method.

Comment: Had the same idea but came here thinking there had to be a better way. Then I see someone implemented my first thought. :-) While it's not the most efficient and probably a bad idea if you are expecting large result sets, for small results it gives maximum flexibility with minimum effort. Nice.

Answer (score 6):

You can install the package `DbDataReaderMapper` with the command `Install-Package DbDataReaderMapper` or using your IDE's package manager.

You can then create your data access object (I will choose a shorter example than the one you provided):

```
class EmployeeDao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

To do the automatic mapping you can call the extension method `MapToObject<T>()`

```
var reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    var employeeObj = reader.MapToObject<EmployeeDao>();
}
```

and you will get rid of tens of lines of unreadable and hardly-maintainable code.

Step-by-step example here: https://github.com/LucaMozzo/DbDataReaderMapper

Answer (score 5):

```
List<T> result = new List<T>();
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{                        
    Type type = typeof(T);
    T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        try
        {
            var value = reader[property.Name];
            if (value != null)
                property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value.ToString(), property.PropertyType));
        }
        catch{}                            
    }
    result.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: suggestion: add "if (reader.HasRows) {}" block and move "while(reader.Read())" block within, and statements "Type type" and "PropertyInfo[] properties" just above "while(reader.Read())" block

Answer (score 1):

There is a [SqlDataReader](https://github.com/grigorgeous/sqldatareader-mapper/) Mapper library in NuGet which helps you to map SqlDataReader to an object. Here is how it can be used (from GitHub documentation):

```
var mappedObject = new SqlDataReaderMapper<DTOObject>(reader)
    .Build();
```

Or, if you want a more advanced mapping:

```
var mappedObject = new SqlDataReaderMapper<DTOObject>(reader)
     .NameTransformers("_", "")
     .ForMember<int>("CurrencyId")
     .ForMember("CurrencyCode", "Code")
     .ForMember<string>("CreatedByUser", "User").Trim()
     .ForMemberManual("CountryCode", val => val.ToString().Substring(0, 10))
     .ForMemberManual("ZipCode", val => val.ToString().Substring(0, 5), "ZIP")
     .Build();
```

Advanced mapping allows you to use name transformers, change types, map fields manually or even apply functions to the object's data so that you can easily map objects even if they differ with a reader.

Comment: This ran 20 times slower for me than other solutions. :(

Comment: @SunnyPatel If you use 1.0.2 version of this library (which actually depends on FastMember), then it'll perform as fast as the solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

I took both pimbrouwers and HouseCat's answers and come up with me. In my scenario, the column name in database has snake case format.

```
public static T ConvertToObject<T>(string query) where T : class, new()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(AutoConfig.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(query) {Connection = conn};
            var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var mappedObject = new T();

            if (!rd.HasRows) return mappedObject;
            var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T));
            var members = accessor.GetMembers();
            if (!rd.Read()) return mappedObject;
            for (var i = 0; i < rd.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var columnNameFromDataTable = rd.GetName(i);
                var columnValueFromDataTable = rd.GetValue(i);

                var splits = columnNameFromDataTable.Split('_');
                var columnName = new StringBuilder("");
                foreach (var split in splits)
                {
                    columnName.Append(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(split.ToLower()));
                }

                var mappedColumnName = members.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                    string.Equals(x.Name, columnName.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                if(mappedColumnName == null) continue;
                var columnType = mappedColumnName.Type;

                if (columnValueFromDataTable != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    accessor[mappedObject, columnName.ToString()] = Convert.ChangeType(columnValueFromDataTable, columnType);
                }
            }

            return mappedObject;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the following class to execute a SQL query and automatically map the rows to objects. You can easily adjust the class to fit to your needs. Beware that our approach depends on [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member), but you could easily modify the code to use reflection.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Mapping configuration for a specific sql table to a specific class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Accessor">Used to access the target class properties.</param>
/// <param name="PropToRowIdxDict">Target class property name -> database reader row idx dictionary.</param>
internal record RowMapper(TypeAccessor Accessor, IDictionary<string, int> PropToRowIdxDict);

public class RawSqlHelperService
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Create a new mapper for the conversion of a <see cref="DbDataReader"/> row -> <typeparamref name="T"/>.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">Target class to use.</typeparam>
  /// <param name="reader">Data reader to obtain column information from.</param>
  /// <returns>Row mapper object for <see cref="DbDataReader"/> row -> <typeparamref name="T"/>.</returns>
  private RowMapper GetRowMapper<T>(DbDataReader reader) where T : class, new()
  {
    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T));
    var members = accessor.GetMembers();

    // Column name -> column idx dict
    var columnIdxDict = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).ToDictionary(idx => reader.GetName(idx), idx => idx);
    var propToRowIdxDict = members
      .Where(m => m.GetAttribute(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false) == null)
      .Select(m =>
      {
        var columnAttr = m.GetAttribute(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false) as ColumnAttribute;
        var columnName = columnAttr == null
          ? m.Name
          : columnAttr.Name;

        return (PropertyName: m.Name, ColumnName: columnName);
      })
      .ToDictionary(x => x.PropertyName, x => columnIdxDict[x.ColumnName]);

    return new RowMapper(accessor, propToRowIdxDict);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Read <see cref="DbDataReader"/> current row as object <typeparamref name="T"/>.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">The class to map to.</typeparam>
  /// <param name="reader">Data reader to read the current row from.</param>
  /// <param name="mapper">Mapping configuration to use to perform the mapping operation.</param>
  /// <returns>Resulting object of the mapping operation.</returns>
  private T ReadRowAsObject<T>(DbDataReader reader, RowMapper mapper) where T : class, new()
  {
    var (accessor, propToRowIdxDict) = mapper;
    var t = new T();

    foreach (var (propertyName, columnIdx) in propToRowIdxDict)
      accessor[t, propertyName] = reader.GetValue(columnIdx);

    return t;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Execute the specified <paramref name="sql"/> query and automatically map the resulting rows to <typeparamref name="T"/>.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">Target class to map to.</typeparam>
  /// <param name="dbContext">Database context to perform the operation on.</param>
  /// <param name="sql">SQL query to execute.</param>
  /// <param name="parameters">Additional list of parameters to use for the query.</param>
  /// <returns>Result of the SQL query mapped to a list of <typeparamref name="T"/>.</returns>
  public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteSql<T>(DbContext dbContext, string sql, IEnumerable<DbParameter> parameters = null) where T : class, new()
  {
    var con = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    await con.OpenAsync();

    var cmd = con.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters?.ToArray() ?? new DbParameter[0]);

    var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    var records = new List<T>();
    var mapper = GetRowMapper<T>(reader);

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
      records.Add(ReadRowAsObject<T>(reader, mapper));
    }

    await con.CloseAsync();

    return records;
  }
}
```

## Mapping Attributes Supported

I implemented support for the attributes **NotMapped** and **Column** used also by the entity framework.

### NotMapped Attribute

Properties decorated with this attribute will be ignored by the mapper.

### Column Attribute

With this attribute the column name can be customized. Without this attribute the property name is assumed to be the column name.

### Example Class

```cs
private class Test
{
  [Column("SDAT")]
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } // Column name = "SDAT"
  public DateTime EDAT { get; set; } // Column name = "EDAT"
  [NotMapped]
  public int IWillBeIgnored { get; set; }
}
```

## Comparision to Reflection

I also compared the approach with FastMember to using plain reflection.

For the comparision I queried two date columns from a table with 1000000 rows, here are the results:

| Approach | Duration in seconds |
| --- | --- |
| FastMember | ~1.6 seconds |
| Reflection | ~2 seconds |

Credits to user [pim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2421277/pim) for inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

This is based on the other answers but I used standard reflection to read the properties of the class you want to instantiate and fill it from the dataReader. You could also store the properties using a dictionary persisted b/w reads.

Initialize a dictionary containing the properties from the type with their names as the keys.

```
var type = typeof(Foo);
var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var propertyDictionary = new Dictionary<string,PropertyInfo>();
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    if (!property.CanWrite) continue;
    propertyDictionary.Add(property.Name, property);
}
```

The method to set a new instance of the type from the DataReader would be like:

```
var foo = new Foo();
//retrieve the propertyDictionary for the type
for (var i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    var n = dataReader.GetName(i);
    PropertyInfo prop;
    if (!propertyDictionary.TryGetValue(n, out prop)) continue;
    var val = dataReader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : dataReader.GetValue(i);
    prop.SetValue(foo, val, null);
}
return foo;
```

If you want to write an efficient generic class dealing with multiple types you could store each dictionary in a global dictionary>.

Answer (score -1):

This kinda works

```
 public static object PopulateClass(object o, SQLiteDataReader dr, Type T)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            T.GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(o, dr[property.Name],null);
        }
        return o;
    }
```

Note I'm using SQlite here but the concept is the same.  As an example I'm filling a Game object by calling the above like this-

```
g = PopulateClass(g, dr, typeof(Game)) as Game;
```

Note you have to have your class match up with datareader 100%, so adjust your query to suit or pass in some sort of list to skip fields.  With a SQLDataReader talking to a SQL Server DB you have a pretty good type match between .net and the database.  With SQLite you have to declare your ints in your class as Int64s for this to work and watch sending nulls to strings.  But the above concept seems to work so it should get you going.  I think this is what the Op was after.