# Why does Newtonsoft.Json work in example and System.Text.Json doesn't

Tags: c#

I found the following example in StackOverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56741885

When I use Newtonsoft, it works like the preceding article link. However, it doesn't work with System.Text.Json; I get the error stated below.

```cs
using DataModelsClassLibrary1;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace DataLayerClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static List<TodoItem> GetAllTodos()
        { 
            var connString = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Database1;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            var dt = new DataTable();

            List<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                  "SELECT * FROM Todo",
                  con);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //var serializedMyObjects = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
                    //// Here you get the object
                    //todos = (List<TodoItem>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedMyObjects, typeof(List<TodoItem>));

                    var serializedMyObjects = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dt);
                    // Here you get the object
                    todos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TodoItem>>(serializedMyObjects);
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            return todos;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and
> deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported. Path:
> $.Columns.DataType.  ---> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization
> and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported.
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.UnsupportedTypeConverter`1.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWriteAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack&
> state)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableConverter`1.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack&
> state)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(WriteStack&
> state, NotSupportedException ex)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteUsingSerializer[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStringUsingSerializer[TValue](TValue&
> value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value,
> JsonSerializerOptions options)    at
> DataLayerClassLibrary1.Class1.GetAllTodos() in  . .

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to serialise a `DataTable` and each `DataColumn` has a `DataType` property that contains a `Type`. The error message is telling you that serialising that data is not supported. If it works with Newtonsoft then obviously it is supported by that library.

Comment: OP could however add a custom type converter.